Why is the heat curve of water a straight line?
This excellent video plots the heat curve of water experimentally by measuring the temperature every second (see below). The apparatus was a Corning PC-400D Hot Plate with a Vernier Go!Temp thermometer.

I was surprised to see the temperature rise in a straight line from 15 C to 99 C. I had expected the rate of rise to decrease with increasing temperature for the following reasons:

Water evaporates faster at higher temperature. Therefore, with rising temperature, more of the heat energy should be consumed in the evaporation of water leading to a smaller increase in the temperature.

With rising temperature, the rate of heat transfer from the hot plate will decrease due to the reduced temperature difference between the temperature of the hot plate and the water beaker.


There is another paper which shows a near-straight line from 20 C to 70 C, and then a fall in the rate of temperature increase above 70 C (see below).
However, they used an immersion heater which is a metal rod heated at constant voltage. The electric resistance of metals increases with temperature, resulting in a fall in the heat produced.

Could the experts here please guide me? I also searched a lot for published experimental results but surprisingly couldn't find any.

Well, it isn’t a straight line. You should also measure the temperature of the hot plate…

@JonCuster Thank you for your comment. This experiment was not conducted by me. I agree that a synchronised plot of the hot plate temperature would have been great.

Just because a mechanism—such as evaporation—exists doesn’t mean that it’s dominant or easily detectable. (For that matter, just because a measurement is taken doesn’t mean it’s accurate.) The temperature profile is approximately a straight line, but I’d expect it to be concave downward, per your reasoning and for other reasons. You could plot the slope over time to evaluate this. A monotonic temperature increase, somewhat concave downward, is exactly what one would expect from a simple material heated vigorously, even assuming constant material properties.

Thank you for your comment. Your answers have always been educative to me. As an expert in this field, could you please help me find any published papers with similar data? I searched a lot but couldn't find any.

Hi John, could you please help me with this question?

It's very possible, depending on the equipment used, that they wanted a constant rate of temperature rise, and the heating device used feedback control to achieve that. That would mean it adjusted the heat input up or down if the temperature started to deviate from the intended profile.

Thank you for your comment. It doesn't seem that any such control mechanism is available in the Corning PC-400D Hot Plate which is a simple lab hot plate. I also searched a lot for published papers but couldn't find any.
